# SQL selecting all that matches

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got this SQL query exercise(#71) from SQL-EX.RU

This exercise involves two table:

1. Product(maker, model, type)
2. PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)

The question is: find all the PC makers who have all their models of PC type in the PC table.

The version I wrote is:

```
SELECT maker FROM 
(SELECT maker, sum(cast(model1 as int)) as sum1, sum(cast(model2 as int)) as sum2 FROM
(SELECT p.maker, p.model as model1, pc.model as model2 FROM product AS p
FULL JOIN pc ON p.model = pc.model 
WHERE p.type = 'PC') AS a
GROUP BY maker) b 
WHERE sum1 = sum2
```

But it doesn't work out perfectly, could anyone point out where I was wrong or offer a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Change Full join to inner join

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? You tagged both.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until you sort out what DB you're working with. (I blame Microsoft for choosing such a generic name for their relational DB.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following works well.  It is easy to understand and it can be easily modified to perform other functions ("find all who are missing only 1" etc)

```
SELECT maker
FROM (
  SELECT maker,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PC.model is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing_count
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN PC ON Product.model = PC.model
  GROUP BY maker
) x
WHERE missing_count = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select Maker
    From Products
    Where Maker Not In
        (
        Select P.Maker -- If one product is not in PC table PC.Code will be null
            From Products P
            Left Join PC On PC.Model = P.Model
            Where PC.Code Is Null
        )
```

Comment: thanks sooooo much! Your way of thinking is right (though do need to add on type = 'pc' to filter pc makers), but after adding that, your answer solve my problem : )